# Not able to make slug work in Django

Tags: python, django

I am building one project in which i used slug for urls. But it doesn't seem to be working. My regex pattern is right I have tested it. I have used id before and then it worked fine but if i use slug in place of id it creates error. Here is my code

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'Category'
      verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'Country'
      verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class News(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'News'
      verbose_name_plural = 'News'

   def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.Home, name='index'),
   url(r'^[a-z0-9-]+$/detail', views.detail, name='detail')]
```

**views.py**

```
def detail(request, slug):
   nd = get_object_or_404(News, slug=slug)
   return render(request, template_name="app/detail.html", context={'nd':nd})
```

**detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Detail{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="home">
    {% for n in nd %}
        <h2>{{ n.title }}</h2>
        <h4>{{ n.category }}</h4>
        <h4>{{ n.pub_date }}</h4>
        <p>{{ n.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: "but if i use slug in place of id it creates error" => And ? Are we supposed to guess which error ? Or are you expecting us to create a whole new django project, database etc to find out by ourselves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it work change

```
url(r'^[a-z0-9-]+$/detail', views.detail, name='detail')
```

to

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/detail/$', views.detail, name='detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not capturing the argument in your URL pattern, so it won't be sent to the view.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)$/detail', views.detail, name='detail')]
```